# Sumar registros en un reportviewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

tengo un reporte en visual basic, lo que necesito es que al final de la pagina me muestre el total de registros que existen.

También necesito que me muestre el total de cada columna (ejemplo: La Columna motivo tiene X cantidad)

Answer (score 1):

hola mira esta es la consulta SQL, donde calculo el totalizador

```
    IF @Tipo='ReporteLiquidacion'
    BEGIN
        --Cabecera
        SELECT      TOP 1            R.facID 'facID'
                                ,Folio_Recompra 'folio_recompra'
                                ,R.Tipo_Operacion 'tipo_oper'
                                ,R.Condicion_Pago 'cond_pago'
                                ,R.Tasa_Captacion 'tasa_capta'
                                ,R.Fecha_de_Pago 'Fecha_de_Pago'

        FROM Facturas F 
        INNER JOIN FIP_VENTA V ON F.facid = V.facid
        INNER JOIN FIP_Recompra R ON v.facID = r.facID
        AND R.facID IN (SELECT facID FROM @tablaFacID)

-- Totalizador cabecera
        SELECT                  SUM(R.Valor_Recompra)  'total_rescate'
        FROM Facturas F 
        INNER JOIN FIP_VENTA V ON F.facid = V.facid
        INNER JOIN FIP_Recompra R ON v.facID = r.facID
        AND R.facID IN (SELECT facID FROM @tablaFacID)


    --Detalle
        SELECT                    R.facID 
                                ,F.cliente 'cliente'
                                ,Folio_Recompra
                                ,CONVERT(INT,F.numero_documento) 'numero_documento'
                                ,CONVERT(INT,F.valor_documento) 'valor_documento'
                                ,R.Valor_Rescate 'Valor_Rescate'
                                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,F.fecha_vencimiento,103) 'fecha_vencimiento'
                                ,R.Interes_por_Recuperar 'Interes_por_Recuperar'--ver si es otro campo
                                ,R.Valor_Recompra 'Valor_Recompra'
                                ,R.Fecha_de_Pago 'Fecha_de_Pago'
                                ,R.Interes_por_Recuperar 'Interes_por_Recuperar'
                                ,R.Monto_Pago 'Monto_Pago'
                                ,R.Tipo_Operacion
                                ,R.Condicion_Pago
                                ,R.Tasa_Captacion
                                ,R.Dias_Reliquidados 'Dias_Reliquidados'
        From Facturas F 
        INNER JOIN FIP_VENTA V ON F.facid = V.facid
        INNER JOIN FIP_Recompra R ON v.facID = r.facID
        AND R.facID IN (SELECT facID FROM @tablaFacID)

    END
```

aqui esta donde hago el evento

```
 protected void Imprimir_Liquidacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BolsaDeProductos.SX.BD.Conexion objconexion = new BolsaDeProductos.SX.BD.Conexion();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Parametros Param = new Parametros();

            Param.Limpiar();
            Param.Agregar("Tipo", "ReporteLiquidacion");
            Param.Agregar("listaFact", objFunciones.Desencriptar(Request.QueryString["listaFact"].ToString()));


            ds = objconexion.EjecutarSQL("spInsertRecompraFIP", Param.Generar("parametros", true));

            ReportViewer liqRecompra = new ReportViewer();

            liqRecompra.LocalReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaDocumento"].ToString() + "Liquidacion_Recompra.rdlc";
            liqRecompra.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            liqRecompra.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("cabecera", ds.Tables[0]));
            liqRecompra.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("total", ds.Tables[1]));
            liqRecompra.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("detalle", ds.Tables[2]));

            byte[] bytes = liqRecompra.LocalReport.Render("Word", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= Comprobante_Liquidacion_Recompra." + extension);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();



        }
```

espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Excelente @Francisco me sirvio de mil maravillas muchas gracias

Comment: @Mario por favor recuerda [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.